# Why does preg_match capture strings that are not inside a capturing group?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match

The default behavior of `preg_match()` is to add the whole matched string itself without the capturing group as the zeroth array element. Then it adds the capturing groups as the next array elements. Is there any way to make sure the matched string is not added to the `$matches` array? Why is it added at all if it is not explicitly captured?

**Example:**

```
$input = 'some23';
preg_match("/some(\d*)/", $input, $matches);
```

results in this `$matches` array:

```
array(
  0  =>  some23
  1  =>  23
)
```

However what I would like to have:

```
array(
  0  =>  23
)
```

Comment: You'll have what you want with a lookbehind `(?<=some)\d*`.

Comment: But even with a lookbehind I get one empty array element when matching for example the string "somebody". I want to make sure `preg_match` only returns a non-empty array when there is a string starting with "some" and followed by a number.

Comment: `preg_match("/some\K\d+/", $input, $matches);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Never would think that it's available